# NoClassDefFoundError with a java bukkit plugin

Tags: java, bungeecord

Here is the code that I get this error with:

```
package me.username.test;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.*;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.Command;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.Plugin;

public class test extends Plugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // You should not put an enable message in your plugin.
        // BungeeCord already does so
        getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "mc" + ChatColor.BLUE + "Hi" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Hi" + " " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "is Safely Enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // You should not put an enable message in your plugin.
        // BungeeCord already does so
        getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "mc" + ChatColor.BLUE + "Hi" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Hi" + " " + ChatColor.RED + "is Disabled");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mfc")){
            getLogger().info(ChatColor.GOLD + "[" + ChatColor.GREEN + "mc" + ChatColor.BLUE + "Fancy" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Chat" + " " + ChatColor.RED + "is Disabled" + ChatColor.GOLD + "]");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I get a `NoClassDefFound` error?

This is a Bukkit Plugin although I based it kinda on a bungeecord tutorial because I wanted something different to do :)

Comment: What do you exactly want to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

On other plugins I see, the class extends 'JavaPlugin' rather than 'Plugin.' I don't know how much impact this will make and if you saw it done like that on a tutorial then fair enough. Another possible problem is that your plugin.yml is not pointing towards this class- again, may not be the problem, but no harm in trying! You should probably copy and post your error so we can see what may be the problem. Your plugin.yml may be helpful too.

Give what i mentioned a try. As i said, no harm in trying- anything that works is great.

Comment: Did you give what i mentioned a try?